# Create a dynamic array of objects by checking uniqueness of a field inside object : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5, ecmascript-2016

I have a requirement of creating a dynamic array of objects, based on checking the uniqueness of a field. I need to form an array with objects of this format

```
[
  { text : "select", label: "select", value: []},
  { text: "abc" , label: "abc" , value: [1,2,3] }
]
```

I have to just  fetch an object that has field "select" and then manipulate that object. If it is not present, then need to create one.Here value is a string array to which elements are pushed into after checking the uniqueness.  .There will be an input string passed, against which the value array will be compared. Suppose "test" is an input , then array should look like,

```
{ text : "select", label: "select", value: ["test1"]}
```

If test1, test2 are passed subsequently then the final array should look like

```
{ text : "select", label: "select", value: ["test1", "test2", "test3"]}
```

If again `test1` is passed, it should not be pushed as it is already present in the array. Comparing should be case insensitive

```
function checkAndPush(arr, inputVal){
     let finalArr = [];
     if (arr?.some((item) => item.text === "select")) { 
         finalArr = [...new Set(arr.map((item) => item.text.toLocaleLowercase() === inputVal.toLocaleLowercase())
     } else {
          finalArr.push({ text : "select", label: "select", value: [inputVal]});
     }
     console.log(finalArr);
}
```

Comment: The then case of your `if` statement produces an array of booleans, the else case puts only a single object in the array. I don't see how you could expect this to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// I guess this is what you trying to do...?

// so you have this obj_list
const obj_list = [
    { text: "select", label: "select", value: ["test1", "test2", "test3"] },
    { text: "abc", label: "abc", value: [1, 2, 3] }
];

// something like button, pressed and input is "test1"
function buttonOnclick(input = "test1") {

    // try to get obj that text is "select"
    let target  = obj_list.find(obj=> obj.text == "select");

    // if not found, creat it and push in to obj_list
    if(!target) {
        target = { text: "select", label: "select", value: [] };
        obj_list.push(target);
    }

    // check value and save result 
    target.value = checkAndPush(target.value, input);
}

function checkAndPush(arr, inputVal) {

    // creat empty array if not exist for some reason
    if (!arr) arr = [];

    // use input array as set
    let current_arr_set = new Set(arr);

    // make value check case insensitive
    inputVal = inputVal.toLocaleLowerCase();

    // if inputVal not in set, push it to arr
    if (!current_arr_set.has(inputVal)) arr.push(inputVal);

    // return edited arr
    return arr;
}
```